# iOS Audio Streaming and save audio file to document directry after audio playing finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, audio-streaming

I want to play audio file from server to my iOS app and after audio playing complete want's to save audio to document directry for offline playing.

I have a code to play audio from server. please provide me any code to save file for offline playing.

```
NSURL *fileURL = // your url.   
myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:AudioFileURL error:nil];
myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
[myAudioPlayer play];
```

Comment: you have to load nsdata and save it to document directry

Comment: Is there any way to save same data while streaming. I do not want to load(run) same url two times.

Comment: no There are not any way i think

Comment: Why not just saved for first time and then check for it in document directory if it saved donot download again .

Comment: Thanks for reply but user first time play the audio file and i do not want to run same url two times one for playing and one for downloading.

Answer (score -1):

I have got a Streaming kit Frame work for this [Audio streaming kit from Github](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit)

Play an MP3 over HTTP

```
STKAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] init];

[audioPlayer play:@"http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/sample.mp3"];
```

And append its data to NSMutabledata to play offline by using this delegate.

Intercept PCM data just before its played

```
[audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
{
  ...
}];
```

Comment: How did you implement this method ?

[audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
{
  ...
}];
Could you please share the code